# VB6 Change Numeric Field To Alphanumeric

Tags: vba, vb6

There is a numeric field in a legacy application that I am trying to change to alphanumeric with a field length of about 15. The field is for data entry of account information. In the code, its referenced at numerous places:

```
.BANK_accno = Format(Me.txtBANK, "####-##-##-##-##")
```

and

```
!BANK_accno = Format(Me.txtBANK, "####-##-##-##-##")
```

The Format is: ####-##-##-##-## and the Mask is ####-##-##-##-##. What I am wondering is what Format (and code) changes should I make to get the field to become alphanumeric? I tried using @@@@@@@@@@, however that has not worked.

Comment: how is BANK_accno  declared?

Comment: Need more information.  "Has not worked" isn't enough to go on.  However, you might try "@@@@-@@-@@-@@-@@" to start with, since that replaces every numeric indicator with an alphanumeric indicator.

Answer (score 0):

As BobRodes commented, you can use `@` to mask characters not limited to numbers. There are other options (ignore spaces, force left-to-right filling, upper/lower case).

Have a look at [Format function documentation at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for details. This link is for VBA but Format strings should be compatible.

Please note that you still need to validate Input, `Format` function is not strict about input.